# Only Integer values when using the GraphView library

Tags: android, android-graphview

I use the awsome GraphView lib to create a graph in my Android App.
But I have a problem. I only want integer values and not double values. I try to custom label formatter but it does not function... 
I think I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what....
Can someone give me a way to explore? (or may be the solution!!!)

thx!

Comment: can you please post the code of your custom formatter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the custom label formatter and just cast the value to Integer.

Try something like that:

```
GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this, "example") {
   @Override
   protected String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
      // return as Integer
      return ""+((int) value);
   }
};
```

Comment: Thx it works!!! thank you very much!! Now I have an other problem but I think I can resolve it! It's a size problem for a BarGraphView. The width of a bar is too small!

Answer (score 1):

Well now formatLabel is deprecated, so overriding it directly is no longer correct.

In newer versions of GraphView, the correct way is to use Custom Label Formatter:

```
graphView.setCustomLabelFormatter(new CustomLabelFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
        // return as Integer
        return ""+((int) value);
    }
});
```